# invalid operands of types ‘int’ and ‘const char [15]’ to binary ‘operator<<’ ^

Tags: c++

I'm trying to do a simple math problem, but I keep getting this error message. What is wrong? I'm using cloud9 ide.

> /home/ubuntu/workspace/Sphere.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
>   /home/ubuntu/workspace/Sphere.cpp:20:63: error: invalid operands of
>   types ‘int’ and ‘const char [15]’ to binary ‘operator<<’
>        cout << "The area of the circle is: " << 3.14*meters^2 << "meters squared" << endl;

Here is the entire code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    // Declare the radius
    int meters;
    cout << "Please enter the radius in meters: ";
    cin >> meters;

    // Calculate Diameter

    cout << "The diameter of the circle is: " << meters*2 << "m" << endl;

    //Calculate Area
    double PI;
    PI = 3.14;

    cout << "The area of the circle is: " << 3.14*meters^2 << "meters squared" << endl;

}
```

Comment: switch >> and <<

Comment: `^` is not what you think is.

Comment: `3.14*meters*meters`

Comment: on a side note: you might consider to write `PI = 4.0 * atan(1.0)` and use `#include <math.h>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C++, the `^` operator does *not* mean exponentiation.  It means to do a bitwise-XOR operation on two integer values.

And since `^` has lower [precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) than `<<`, the compiler interprets your statement as

```
((cout << "The area of the circle is: ") << (3.14*meters)) ^
    ((2 << "meters squared") << endl);
```

and gets hung up on what `2 << "meters squared"` is supposed to do.

In general, C++ has [`std::pow`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow) for exponentiation.  But it's overkill for just squaring a number, and it's probably better to just multiply that number by itself:

```
std::cout << "The area of the circles is: " << 3.14*meters*meters 
          << " meters squared" << std::endl;
```

Comment: `std::pow` is for floating point exponentiation,  I wouldn't suggest using it for integers in any case due to rounding errors